# Dynamic Programming and Functional Programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, dynamic-programming

Is there any example or reference which demonstrates a Dynamic programming solution which has been built with Functional Programming principles. I have seen some Haskell examples with lazy evaluation, but can anyone give a JavaScript example.

Comment: What "functional programming principles" do you refer to? Did you find any JS examples that lacked some of them?

Comment: Which DP algorithm are you interested in specifically?

Comment: Try reading [this](http://buzzdecafe.github.io/code/2014/05/16/introducing-ramda/), which is introduction to pure function javascript library Ramda.

Comment: Hi @bergi, thanks. I just began to study and appreciate functional programming and I was trying to si=olve some problems with it.

Comment: Hi @bergi, thanks. I just began to study and appreciate functional programming and I was trying to solve some problems with it.

In the imperative style dynamic programming is usually a trick to improve the efficiency of some problems, but I wanted to see if there was anyway to do it while sticking to FP as well. The principles I was referring to were: Pure functions, Lazy evaluation, immutability etc...

Comment: @sim thank you for pointing me to ramda. I only knew of lodash and underscore before, but this seems interesting.

Comment: @user3024231: One could argue that dynamic programming is just the explicit (imperative) evaluation of a pure, recursive function by creating a table of immutable results, which you could have gotten for free with lazy evaluation (which I personally don't consider to be part of functional programming).